# Splash screen covering PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, splash-screen, preferenceactivity

have an Activity extending PreferenceActivity opening like so, 
[PreferenceActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdX1j.png)
but when i add a splash screen to the app with:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen_frameup</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

when i navigate to the PreferenceActivity, the toolbar remains but the whole screen is my splash screen (black screen)[PreferenceActivity after apptheme background declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGvNM.png). i have a feeling it is due to the PreferenceActivity not having a declared xml layout? how do i have the splash screen but not have it overlap the PreferenceActivity?

Comment: Picture didnt load, attempting to edit

Comment: please explain the scenario step by step (adding images would be great)

Comment: I apologize for the unclear post, I was debugging after dinner and drinks. Adding "android:windowBackground" in the style created a splash screen, but in doing so it made 1 out of 4 activities be covered by the splash screen. I wrote more detail in the comment on the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be high chance that your are using the same theme for PreferenceActivity too!

Reason: windowBackground!
Create another theme without windowBackground flag & assign that theme to PreferenceActivity...

If that doesn't work, please elaborate more. :)

Comment: This worked. Thank you. I created a style w/o windowBackground attribute and set the style for the PreferenceActivity in the manifest. Now the PreferenceActivity can be seen. Why is that though? 4 other activities are not effected. Is it because that PreferenceActivity doesn't have an xml file to manipulate/inflate? The Android framework seems to generate the UI automatically for the PreferenceActivity.

Comment: @JZudell well that's strange that other Activities aren't affected... But you should still create a separate Style for those 4 Activities, just to be on a safer side! :)